# Django - Form FileField error "This field is required"

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to add Post form into my django project and I've got problem with FileFiled. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = [
        'author',
        'image',
        'title',
        'body'
    ]
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    image = models.FileField(default="", blank=False, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If it helps. I also set `enctype="multipart/form-data` in `<form>`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='path')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

you need to mention the upload_path in the filefield

add `enctype="multipart/form-data` to your form

and in view to get the files

```
PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

if you need to make the field optional

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.FileField(required=False)
   class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = [
        'author',
        'image',
        'title',
        'body'
    ]
```

Answer (score 12):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

You need to pass `request.FILES` to the bound form.

```
bound_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: i just ended up here after fixing some other problems like `upload_to` in models and `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in html form tag and it's working